# Dynamic SQL Pivot parameters query Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a query which is working great when I used it in SQL Server Management Studio. It is worth to mention here that in `PIVOT` `[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName]` and `[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName]` are NOT static and can vary a.k.a they can be change during run time with different columns

```
WITH pivot_data AS
(
    SELECT 
        [p].RecordId, -- Grouping Column
        [Key], -- Spreading Column
        [Value] -- Aggregate Column
    FROM 
        [RecordDatas] AS [p]
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT [p0].*
         FROM [Records] AS [p0]
         WHERE [p0].[IsDeleted] = 0) AS [t] ON [p].[RecordId] = [t].[ID]
    WHERE
        [p].DatasetId = 1386
        AND [p].[IsDeleted] = 0
        AND ([t].[ProjectID] = 191)
        AND [Key] IN ('MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName', 
                      'MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName')
)
SELECT 
    RecordId, 
    [MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName], 
    [MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName]
FROM 
    pivot_data
PIVOT 
    (MAX([Value]) 
     FOR [Key] IN ([MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName], 
                   [MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName])) AS p
```

The problem occurs when I'm trying to build the same query dynamic from C#:

```
var sql1 = @"
            WITH pivot_data AS
(
SELECT [p].RecordId, -- Grouping Column
[Key], -- Spreading Column
[Value] -- Aggregate Column
FROM [RecordDatas] AS [p]
INNER JOIN (
SELECT [p0].*
FROM [Records] AS [p0]
WHERE [p0].[IsDeleted] = 0
) AS [t] ON [p].[RecordId] = [t].[ID]
where [p].DatasetId = 1386
AND [p].[IsDeleted] = 0
AND ([t].[ProjectID] = 191)
AND  [Key] IN( {0} , {1}))
SELECT RecordId, {2},{3}
FROM pivot_data
PIVOT (max([Value]) FOR [Key] IN ({2},{3})) AS p;";

await repositoryMapper.Repository.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql1, 
"MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName", 
"MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName", 
"[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName]", 
"[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName]");
```

And here is coming my problem - when query is generated with `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` and adding parameters for the PIVOT columns (`[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName]` and `[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName]`) there is something wrong with syntax. I'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@p2'.

I have tried to get the generated query which Entity Framework is doing and it looks like this :

```
exec sp_executesql N'
            WITH pivot_data AS
(
SELECT [p].RecordId, -- Grouping Column
[Key], -- Spreading Column
[Value] -- Aggregate Column
FROM [RecordDatas] AS [p]
INNER JOIN (
SELECT [p0].*
FROM [Records] AS [p0]
WHERE [p0].[IsDeleted] = 0
) AS [t] ON [p].[RecordId] = [t].[ID]
where [p].DatasetId = 1386
AND [p].[IsDeleted] = 0
AND ([t].[ProjectID] = 191)
AND  [Key] IN( @p0 , @p1))
SELECT RecordId, @p2,@p3
FROM pivot_data
PIVOT (max([Value]) FOR [Key] IN (@p2,@p3)) AS p;
',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),
@p1 nvarchar(4000),
@p2 nvarchar(4000),
@p3 nvarchar(4000)',
@p0=N'MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName',
@p1=N'MedicalInfo rmation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName',
@p2=N'[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName]',
@p3=N'[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName]'
```

Please help me I'm not sure what is the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a line like this:

SELECT RecordId, @p2,@p3

is not valid. Statements are precompiled and you can not change field names in parameters - field names for a statement are static.

You have to go into dynamic SQL, which EntityFramework does not support (outside of the functions allowing you to submit whatever SQL you want). Basically you must create the valid statement in a way that is NOT using parameters are field names.

This does NOT mean you can not use placeholders and - in C# - run a replace operation on the string, but it means that the replacement has to be finished when you THEN submit the changed script to the database.

Limitation of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign value of these `@p2`,`@p3` in `SELECT RecordId, @p2,@p3` from parameter. You need to set these statement before running query as follow:

```
var sql1 = @"
            WITH pivot_data AS
(
SELECT [p].RecordId, -- Grouping Column
[Key], -- Spreading Column
[Value] -- Aggregate Column
FROM [RecordDatas] AS [p]
INNER JOIN (
SELECT [p0].*
FROM [Records] AS [p0]
WHERE [p0].[IsDeleted] = 0
) AS [t] ON [p].[RecordId] = [t].[ID]
where [p].DatasetId = 1386
AND [p].[IsDeleted] = 0
AND ([t].[ProjectID] = 191)
AND  [Key] IN( {0} , {1}))
SELECT RecordId, [MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName],[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName]
FROM pivot_data
PIVOT (max([Value]) FOR [Key] IN ({2},{3})) AS p;";

await repositoryMapper.Repository.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql1, 
"MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName", 
"MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName", 
"[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.firstName]", 
"[MedicalInformation.MedicalInformationForm.Name.lastName]");
```